# Export Python Dictionary to Geojson - Remove from 'coordinates' value the double quote

Tags: python, json, dictionary, geojson

The [Geojson format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoJSON#Example) is essentially almost regular JSON, except the `coordinates` key:

```
{ 
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": 
        {
            "type": "LineString",
            "coordinates": [
                [10, 20], [30, 40]
            ]
        }
}
```

The difference from regular JSON is that the value of key `coordinates` is without the double quote (in GIS we call it the raw geometry data).

In Python regular JSON can be simply regular `dict()` - So for the sake of simplicity this is how I want to store the Geojson data & export it:

```
# example fr single feature Geojson file
geojson_dict = dict()
geojson_dict['type'] = 'FeatureCollection'
geojson_dict['features'] = []
geojson_dict['features'].append(dict())
geojson_dict['features'][0]['type'] = 'Feature'
geojson_dict['features'][0]['geometry'] = dict()
geojson_dict['features'][0]['geometry']['type'] = 'LineString'
geojson_dict['features'][0]['geometry']['coordinates'] = '['+coordinates_as_string+']'
geojson_dict['features'][0]['properties'] = dict()
geojson_dict['features'][0]['properties']['id'] = 123
with open('filename.geojson', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(geojson_dict, outfile, indent=4)
```

**My question:**

Is there a way to keep using Pythonic dictionary (or similar container), and get rid of the double quotes for specific value? Since Pythonic dictionary by default put's double quotes around any key and value (as regular JSON).

**Note:**

I'm not looking into solutions kind of iterating over the key-values with `if key == 'coordinates'` and writing it to text file etc.

Comment: Aren't the values in the co-ordinates list already without the double quotes? Do you want to "add" double-quotes around one value and remove for another specific value?

Comment: @user8212173 No. it's: "coordinates" : "[[1,2], [2,3]]". Should be [[1,2], [2,3]]

Comment: If you have the coordinates as a list, what happens if you replace `geojson_dict['features'][0]['geometry']['coordinates'] = '['+coordinates_as_string+']'` with `geojson_dict['features'][0]['geometry']['coordinates'] = coordinates_as_list`?

Comment: @ASGM it's the same, the '['+ is because according to Geojson spec coordiantes are "list of lists". The important thing is that Python dic = json = automatically wrap any key/value with double quotes.

Comment: GeoJSON *is* JSON. Just call `json.loads(geojson_text)` to get Python objects. If you have a JSON file where the coordinates are quoted, it isn't GeoJSON, it's a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Values (and keys, for that matter) of a python dictionary don't necessarily need to be strings. In fact, you already used a list as value for the key 'features'.

You can simply specify the list of list in the coordinates field.

```
geojson_dict['features'][0]['geometry']['coordinates'] = [[10, 20], [30, 40]]
```

Also, I suggest you to take a look ad the [GeoJSON package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geojson). It's a useful library to handle GeoJSON objects (geometries, features, collections).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `literal_eval()` function in the `ast` library to remove double-quotes from dictionary values. In the JSON data provided, we could do something like this:

```
import ast
geo = { 
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": 
        {
            "type": "LineString",
            "coordinates": "[[10, 20], [30, 40]]"
        }
}

v = geo['geometry']["coordinates"]
geo['geometry']["coordinates"] = ast.literal_eval(v)
print(geo)

Output: {'type': 'Feature', 'geometry': {'type': 'LineString', 'coordinates': [[10, 20], [30, 40]]}}
```